# Doctrine 2, creating EntityManager from PDO - error

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I have the following scenario:

```
class ModelManager extends EntityManager implements ModelManagerInterface
{

    public function __construct($conn, $options = array())
    {
        $isDev = empty($options['is_dev']) ? false : $options['is_dev'];

        // @see Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#create()
        $config = ArrayUtils::arrayMergeRecursiveRight($options, array(
            'cache' => $isDev ? new Cache\ArrayCache : new Cache\ApcCache,
            'queryCache' => $isDev ? new Cache\ArrayCache : new Cache\ApcCache,
            'modelsProxiesPath' => getcwd() . '/cache/ModelProxies',
        ));

        // create Configuration object
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $config = $this->initConfig($options);
            if (!$config->getMetadataDriverImpl()) {
                throw ORMException::missingMappingDriverImpl();
            }
        }

        // test EventManager object
        $eventManager = empty($options['eventManager']) ? new EventManager() : $options['eventManager'];

        switch (true) {
            case ($conn instanceof \PDO):
                $conn = array(
                    'driver' => 'pdo_' . $conn->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME),
                    'pdo' => $conn,
                );
                print_r($conn);
                $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($conn, $config, $eventManager);
                break;

            case (is_string($conn)):
                $pdo = new \PDO($conn);
                if ('oci8' !== $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME)) {
                    $conn = array(
                        'driver' => 'pdo_' . $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME),
                        'pdo' => $pdo,
                    );
                } else {
                    $conn = $this->mapDsnToDoctrine($conn);
                }
                $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($conn, $config, $eventManager);
                break;

            case (is_array($conn)):
                $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($conn, $config, $eventManager);
                break;

            case ($conn instanceof Connection):
                if ($eventManager !== null && $conn->getEventManager() !== null) {
                    throw ORMException::mismatchedEventManager();
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception\InvalidArgument("Invalid argument: " . json_encode($conn));
        }

        // parent constructor
        // @see Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#__construct()
        parent::__construct($conn, $config, $conn->getEventManager());
    }
// ...
}
```

This is used smth like this:

```
self::$em = new ModelManager(
    new \PDO(self::$config['db_adapter']['connection']['dsn']),
    empty(self::$config['db_adapter']['options']['doctrine']) ?
        array() : self::$config['db_adapter']['options']['doctrine']
);

$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool(self::$em);
$classes = $this->db(self::$config['db_adapter']['options']['doctrine']['modelsPath']);
$tool->updateSchema($classes);
```

Where the config looks like this:

```
$config = array(
    'db_adapter' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'dsn' => 'mysql://root:******@localhost/netistest' . time(),
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'doctrine' => array(
                'cache' => 'ArrayCache|ApcCache', // development|testing&production
                'queryCache' => 'ArrayCache|ApcCache', // development|testing&production
                'modelsPath' => __DIR__ . '/NetisTest/Model',
                'modelsProxiesPath' => __DIR__ . '/cache/doctrine/ModelProxies',
                'modelsProxiesNamespace' => 'App\Models\Proxies',
                'modelsProxiesAutogenerate' => 'App\Models\Proxies',
            ),
            'zend' => array(
                // at this moment we decided not to implement Zend\DbAdapter
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

The problem with all this strange configuration, is that, after instantiating the ModelManager class, when trying to interrogate the database for creating the tables associated to my models, it throws the following error:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'':

SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:91
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:699
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:630
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:206
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:250
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:986
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php:855
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php:832
/home/dragosc/workspace/athem-repositories/Component_NetisDb/tests/NetisTest/Db/Setup/Doctrine.php:51
```

You can find the code (however in an older form) here as well: 
https://github.com/athemcms/Component_NetisDb/blob/master/library/Netis/Db/ModelManager/ModelManager.php

Can anyone please help me in understanding why PDO isn't enough for EntityManager to remember the database as well ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your DSN doesn't look right. See http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: The EntityManager is not designed to be extended.  I suspect you could move your functionality to custom repositories instead.  However, if you are determined to extend EntityManager then copy the static factory method EntityManager::create to your ModelManager and adjust it.

Comment: @Phil When I wrote my DSN parser, I first looked here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php which it seems it works only for PEAR::DB.

Comment: @Cerad, yes you can extend that class; it's actually more of a wrapper, and yes I did copy the code from EntityManager::create. Problem was different; see comment to Phil.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Was pretty usefull :D.